# Is there a way to preload all pages in WPF

Tags: wpf, performance, mvvm, data-binding, preload

I'm building an application using WPF. I have a HostFrame on my Main Window where I'm binding to the CurrentPage property on my ViewModel. CurrentPage is an enum containing names of all pages. I also have a converter that converts the name of the current page to the actual page. My converter takes the pages from NInject dependency container and returns the corresponding page. All of my pages are created when the application is started inside the dependency container. Now, the problem is that I'm experiencing lag and slow performances when navigating through different pages. I would like to have something like a loading screen when the app starts for the first time and preload all pages and then when all pages are preloaded remove the loading screen. I don't know how to preload the pages.

HostFrame.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.HostFrame"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="562" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Grid.Row="1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="OldPage"></Frame>
        <Frame Grid.Row="1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="NewPage"></Frame>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

HostFrame.xaml.cs

```
namespace Client
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for HostFrame.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class HostFrame : UserControl
    {
        public BasePage CurrentPage

        {
            get { return (BasePage)GetValue(CurrentPageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CurrentPageProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentPageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CurrentPage), typeof(BasePage), typeof(HostFrame), new UIPropertyMetadata(CurrentPagePropertyChanged));

        private static void CurrentPagePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the frames
            var newPageFrame = (d as HostFrame).NewPage;
            var oldPageFrame = (d as HostFrame).OldPage;

            // Store the current page content as the old page
            var oldPageContent = newPageFrame.Content;

            // Remove current page from new page frame
            newPageFrame.Content = null;

            // Move the previous page into the old page frame
            oldPageFrame.Content = oldPageContent;

            // Animate out previous page when the Loaded event fires
            // right after this call due to moving frames
            if (oldPageContent is BasePage oldPage)
                oldPage.ShouldAnimateOut = true;

            // Set the new page content
            newPageFrame.Content = e.NewValue;

        }

        public void NavigateToPage(Page newPage)
        {
            // Set the content of the NewPage frame to the specified page
            NewPage.Content = newPage;
        }
        public HostFrame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Dependency Container

```
    public class IocContainer
    {
        public static IKernel Kernel { get; private set; } = new StandardKernel();

        public static void Setup()
        {
            BindViewModels();
        }

        private static void BindViewModels()
        {
            Kernel.Bind<ApplicationViewModel>().ToConstant(new ApplicationViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<MainViewModel>().ToConstant(new MainViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<LoginViewModel>().ToConstant(new LoginViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<LoginView>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();
            Kernel.Bind<SideMenuViewModel>().ToConstant(new SideMenuViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<SideMenuUserControl>().ToConstant(new SideMenuUserControl());
            Kernel.Bind<DashboardViewModel>().ToConstant(new DashboardViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<Dashboard>().ToConstant(new Dashboard());
            Kernel.Bind<MembersViewModel>().ToConstant(new MembersViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<Members>().ToConstant(new Members());
            Kernel.Bind<RegistrationViewModel>().ToConstant(new RegistrationViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<Registration>().ToConstant(new Registration());
            Kernel.Bind<InventoryViewModel>().ToConstant(new InventoryViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<Inventory>().ToConstant(new Inventory()); 
            Kernel.Bind<CalendarViewModel>().ToConstant(new CalendarViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<Calendar>().ToConstant(new Calendar());
            Kernel.Bind<ShopViewModel>().ToConstant(new ShopViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<Shop>().ToConstant(new Shop());

            Kernel.Bind<HomeViewModel>().ToConstant(new HomeViewModel());
            Kernel.Bind<HomeView>().ToConstant(new HomeView());


            // Popups
            Kernel.Bind<AddNewItem>().ToConstant(new AddNewItem());
            Kernel.Bind<Overlay>().ToConstant(new Overlay());
        }

        public static T Get<T>()
        {
            return Kernel.Get<T>();
        }
    }
```

Page converter

```
   public class ApplicationPageValueConverter : BaseValueConverter<ApplicationPageValueConverter>
   {
       public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           switch ((ApplicationPage)value)
           {
               case ApplicationPage.Home:
                   return IocContainer.Get<HomeView>();

               case ApplicationPage.Dashboard:
                   return IocContainer.Get<Dashboard>();      
               
               case ApplicationPage.Members:
                   return IocContainer.Get<Members>();

               case ApplicationPage.Register:
                   return IocContainer.Get<Registration>();

               case ApplicationPage.Calendar:
                   return IocContainer.Get<Calendar>();

               case ApplicationPage.Inventory:
                   return IocContainer.Get<Inventory>();

               case ApplicationPage.Shop:
                   return IocContainer.Get<Shop>();

               case ApplicationPage.Login:
                   return IocContainer.Get<LoginView>();

               default:
                   Debugger.Break();
                   return null;
           }
       }

       public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
```

MainWindow

```
            <local:HostFrame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MainFrame" Panel.ZIndex="1"
                     DataContext="{Binding ApplicationViewModel.CurrentPage,
                     Converter={local:ApplicationPageValueConverter}, 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                     CurrentPage ="{Binding}">
            </local:HostFrame>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend viewmodel first and data templating views from viewmodels. Here's a very simple example. https://github.com/AndyONeill/WPF_NavigationViewModelFirst  also. Why are you using DI at all?

Comment: Because i can access any viewmodel from anywhere in the application. It makes easier to change things from one page on another. I dont have a lot of experience with wpf. This is the first time i hear about "viewmodel first" concept. I'm not sure how it is going to resolve performance issues.

Comment: Also I thought since all pages are created only once in the Dependency container when the application loads it will be snappier, but that was not the case

Comment: Im looking for something like page.Load() and if(page.IsLoaded) goToPage()

Comment: Even when doing heavy loading inside the viewmodel I do not have a "laggy" application, maybe because I do async initialization of the viewmodels. Each VM has an ÌnitializeAsync` method and that is called in the `Loaded` event of a `Page`/`Window` - [see this example](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-77657479-PageNavigation/blob/master/WpfApp/Views/QueryPage.xaml.cs#L15)

Comment: My problem is probably related to animations. All my viewmodels are instantiated in my dependency container when application runs for the first time so i dont think that is the problem.